# Delphi [PAClient Error] Error: E6660 Could not find program, '/usr/bin/actool' in a macincloud enviroment

Tags: delphi, mac-in-cloud

I work with Delphi 10.4 latest version.
I have an macInCloud account to compile apps for iOS.
I have installed the latest PAServer on the mac machine. (created from scratch).
In SDK manager i have syncronized the iPhoneOS12.1 version.
Now when I want to deploy an app, the following error appear:

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E6660 Could not find program, '/usr/bin/actool'
```

Any advice?

Comment: In a terminal window on the macInCloud machine, run this command: ls /usr/bin/actool. If it says "No such file or directory", then run this command: /usr/bin/xcrun -f actool. It will either report "unable to find utility "actool"" or it will display the path to it

Comment: Hi all. The problem is because mismatch of XCODE and delphi. XCODE is not latest version and dont have that utility. After installing XCODE 11+ (and working with sku13.5) is working fine.