# Problem compiling iOS app with Delphi 10.4 and XCode 10.1 - could not find /usr/bin/actool

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, delphi

This is related to the XCode 10.1 I installed.
(10.1 is the highest version I can install with MacOS High Sierra, which my machine supports up till)

Delphi 10.4, XCode 10.1 with Command Tools & Additional Tools.

I got this error when compiling:

[PAClient Error] Error: E6660 Could not find program, '/usr/bin/actool'

I already checked forum for similar questions:

[Delphi [PAClient Error] Error: E6660 Could not find program, '/usr/bin/actool' in a macincloud enviroment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592641/delphi-paclient-error-error-e6660-could-not-find-program-usr-bin-actool-i)

I checked "actool" using /usr/bin/xcrun -f actool

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool

Is it because my actool is located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool
but Delphi is trying to find it in /usr/bin/actool ?

How do I tell Delphi to use /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool
or how do I move/copy  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool
to /usr/bin/actool

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either update Xcode (which you should anyway) preferably to Xcode 11.5 (because there's an issue with Delphi importing iOS 14 from Xcode 12), which you can get from here if you have a developer account: https://developer.apple.com/download

..or open a Terminal window and:

```
cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool /usr/bin
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the reply.  I'm not able to run Xcode 11.5 due to MacOS version constraint.  I tried cp... command it says Permission Denied.  I disabled Mac's SIP.  Users-iMac:~ user$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
Users-iMac:~ user$ cp /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool /usr/bin
cp: /usr/bin/actool: Permission denied

Comment: Try with sudo before cp, i.e. `sudo cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool /usr/bin`

Comment: It seems almost impossible to copy files to /usr/bin even though SIP already disabled.  Is there another workaround?  For example, telling Delphi where the actool is found... or any other way to copy to /usr/bin?  I'm using MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: Hi Dave, all the googling didn't solve the problem; you did! thanks so much! Really appreciate the solution!